# Providing call for all returns @@redux-saga/IO

Tags: redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I'm trying to make a test using `redux-test-saga-test-plan` and `describe` but I'm having troubles on the yielded return.
The target to being tested is the next slice of code:

```
const { tenantDocuments, feedDocuments, historicalDocuments } = yield all({
        feedDocuments: call(__searchDocument, timezone, validUrl, feedId, 'feed', provider),
        tenantDocuments: call(__searchDocument, timezone, validUrl, feedId, 'tenant'),
        historicalDocuments: call(__searchDocument, timezone, validUrl, feedId, 'global')
});
```

`__searchDocument` is a generator function and the return comes from another generator , I mean it returns the result of another generator: `return yield __getDocuments(documentIds);`

The `expectSaga` it's something like (I removed a lot of code only leaving the provide part and something of context):

```
  expectSaga(sagas)
    .withReducer(reducers)
    .withState(getFullState({state}))
    .provide([
                [matchers.call.fn(Api.prototype.get), dynamic(test.searchApiMock)],
                [matchers.call.fn(Api.prototype.post), dynamic(test.documentsApiMock)]
            ])
            .put(operators.setLoading({ loading: true }))
            .dispatch(operators.changeStep({ step: "SELECT_FOUND_DOCUMENTS" }))
            .hasFinalState(getFullState(state))
            .silentRun();
    });
```

As you see I have provided to `matchers.call.fn` for 3rd party API calls. And I put on dynamic another function, those functions from now are only returning plain objects and nothing else.

Then, when I try to check the content for example of `feedDocuments`.

The content of those vars are like:

```
 { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
        CALL:
         { context: null,
           fn:
            { [Function: sagaWrapper] '@@redux-saga-test-plan/saga-wrapper': true },
           args: [ Object [Generator] {}, [Function: refineYieldedValue] ] }
```

In other hand if I change the sagas code from `yield all({...})` to something like:

```
const feedDocuments = yield __searchDocument(..);
cosnt tenantDocuments = yield __searchDocument(..);
const historicalDocuments = yield __searchDocument(..);
```

The test & mock works as expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? And why the `all` seems that is not properly mocked?